# adding values from an array to object javascript

Tags: javascript, for-loop

I have an array.

```
var nestedArr =[['loop0', 0], ['loop1', 1], ['loop2', 2], ['loop3', 3], ['loop4', 4], ['loop5', 5]]
```

I have to get using for loop this:

```
var obj = { loop0: 0, loop1: 1, loop2: 2 ...};
```

I am trying this :

```
for(var j = 0; j < nestedArr.length; j++){
    obj[nestedArr[j][0]] = nestedArr[j][1]}
```

but I am getting values as undefined. How do I add values correctly.

Comment: Can you provide a code snippet on jsFiddle or something similar? I dont really understand your problem.

Comment: with a declared and initialized `var obj = {}`, the code works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working fine for me. Just added the definition of `obj`

```js
var nestedArr =[['loop0', 0], ['loop1', 1], ['loop2', 2], ['loop3', 3], ['loop4', 4], ['loop5', 5]],
     obj = {};

for(var j = 0; j < nestedArr.length; j++){

obj[nestedArr[j][0]] = nestedArr[j][1]

}

console.log(obj)
```

Comment: it does not explain why *but I am getting values as undefined*.

Comment: because it is not giving you _undefined_

Answer (score 1):

You can use `reduce` function as below:

```js
var nestedArr = [
  ['loop0', 0],
  ['loop1', 1],
  ['loop2', 2],
  ['loop3', 3],
  ['loop4', 4],
  ['loop5', 5]
];

var output = {};

nestedArr.reduce(function(itm) {
  output[itm[0]] = itm[1];

});

console.log(output);
```

Your loop also is correct:

```js
var nestedArr = [
  ['loop0', 0],
  ['loop1', 1],
  ['loop2', 2],
  ['loop3', 3],
  ['loop4', 4],
  ['loop5', 5]
];

var obj = {};

for (var j = 0; j < nestedArr.length; j++) {

  obj[nestedArr[j][0]] = nestedArr[j][1]

}

console.log(obj)
```

Comment: I wasn't the downvoter, but `.map` is not appropriate when you aren't returning anything - use `.reduce` instead

Comment: map ... without using the result. btw the given code of op works.

Comment: I change it to `reduce`

Comment: @Satpal Why `forEach`? If reducing an array into an object, that's exactly what `reduce` is for

Comment: Your for loop is correct and you see it runs well. whats the problem? @blahblahvah

Answer (score 0):

Using `Array.prototype.reduce` you can do this.

```js
var nestedArr =[['loop0', 0], ['loop1', 1], ['loop2', 2], ['loop3', 3], ['loop4', 4], ['loop5', 5]]

const res = nestedArr.reduce((acc, v) => {
  acc[v[0]] = v[1];
  return acc;
}, {});

console.log(res);
```